# Timestamp issue in Time Travel feature in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to SnowFlake. I created a table in Snowflake. Below are the details.

```
# Created @ 2020-01-07 21:11:20.810 -0800
CREATE TABLE employee2(
emp_id INT,
f_name STRING,
l_name STRING,
dept STRING);
```

When I am trying to get time travel data using below command, it gives me error.

**Query:**

```
select * from employee2 at(timestamp => '2020-01-07 21:12:20.810 -0800'::timestamp);
```

**Error:**
Time travel data is not available for table EMPLOYEE2. The requested time is either beyond the allowed time travel period or before the object creation time.

Although the following command works well.

```
SELECT * FROM employee2 at(offset => -60 * 2);
```

Any hep on this would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Neeraj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duration for the Time travel feature varies from account to account. You need to check what kind of account you have created (Standard/Enterprise etc). The retention policy is 1 day for the standard version and 90 days for the enterprise version.

I also suggest setting the timezone before you play with this feature for better accuracy

```
ALTER SESSION  SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

and then trying running this query. Minor alteration at your millisecond part.

```
select * from employee2 before(timestamp => '2020-01-07 21:12:20.810'::timestamp);
```

The AT clause is used for offset so when you are using timestamp or any field, use the BEFORE keyword.

```
--time travel 2 min ago
SELECT * FROM employee2 at(offset => -60 * 2);
```

Hope this helps, if not, please share your comment and error with a screenshot.

Comment: @H Roy : Changing the session timezone to 'UTC' fixed the issue. Appreciate your quick help & resolution.

Answer (score 3):

If the timestamp is in the local timezone, try to cast to the `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` datatype instead:

```
select * from employee2 at(timestamp => '2020-01-07 21:12:20.810 -0800'::timestamp_ltz);
```