# Snowflake query not working from Databricks while reading

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I have query as below.

```
SELECT * FROM Sample CHANGES(INFORMATION => DEFAULT) AT(TIMESTAMP => '2023-05-10 00:43:34.885 -7000')
```

I want to read the data from the databricks. Timestamp is giving an issue. The above query working in snowflake but not in databricks.
Please let me know what the issue is here.
Below is the error.

```
Time travel data is not available for table Sample. The requested time is either beyond the allowed time travel period or before the object creation time.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timestamp issue in Time Travel feature in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643350/timestamp-issue-in-time-travel-feature-in-snowflake)

Comment: No. Here my query is working in snowflake. In databricks and snowflake same time format, same timezone. Problem is In Databricks I am getting a problem while reading into Dataframe using that query.

Comment: @Adi As per the documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes#:~:text=If%20requested%20data%20is,extended)%2C%20the%20statement%20fails. - Does the link possibly solve/explain your issue ? What edition are you using and what is the time travel period for it ? Also please try the example in the link i.e. using a current timestamp as a variable - as the link mentions that `TIMESTAMP => timestamp Specifies an exact date and time to use for Time Travel. Note that the value must be explicitly cast to a TIMESTAMP.`

Comment: Is the Databricks table set up as part of a Delta lake?  The error seems to imply time travel isn't enabled for that table.

Comment: This issue resolved after doing cast of the timestamp. and given -0700 instead of 7000